# Fatal Error : Cannot use object of type as array

Tags: php, arrays, object

So, I this error appeared when I try to get a list of array from object singleton.

This one is the singleton on CardType.php

```
class CardTypeAPIAccessor extends GuzzleClient
{

    private $client;

    public function __construct($client) 
    {
        if($client instanceof GuzzleClient)
        {
            $this->client = $client;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->client = parent::getClient();
        }
    }

    public function getCardTypes() {
        $cardTypes = array();

        try 
        {

            $response = $this->client->get('admin/card/type',
                ['headers' => ['Authorization' => $_SESSION['login']['apiKey']]
            ]);

            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
            // Check that the request is successful.
            if ($statusCode == 200) 
            {
                $error = $response->json();
                foreach ($error['types'] as $type) 
                {
                    $cardType = new CardType();
                    $cardType->setCardTypeId($type['card_type_id']);
                    $cardType->setCategory($type['category']);

                    array_push($cardTypes, $cardType);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(RequestException $e) 
        {
            //todo
            echo $e->getRequest() . "</br>";
            if ($e->hasResponse()) 
            {
                echo $e->getResponse() . "</br>";
            }
        }
        return $cardTypes;      
    }
}
```

And this is the code on card_type.php

```
<?php
     $cardTypes = $cardTypeAPIAccessor->getCardTypes();
     foreach ($cardTypes as $cardType){
     $Type = new CardType();
?>
     <tr>
        <!-- The error is here-->
        <td class="numeric"><?php echo $Type->getCardTypeId($cardType['card_type_id']); ?></td>
        <td class="numeric"><?php echo $Type->getCategory($cardType['category']); ?></td>
     </tr>
```

The error said :Cannot use object of type CardType as array

Is my code went wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Which line number? Can you bold it or something?

Comment: on this code `<td class="numeric"><?php echo $Type->getCardTypeId($cardType['card_type_id']); ?></td>
        <td class="numeric"><?php echo $Type->getCategory($cardType['category']); ?></td>`

Comment: Basically changing `$cardType['card_type_id']` into `$cardType->card_type_id` should do the trick. If you want to debug then just use `var_dump($cardType); die();` before the error line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have already gotten all values necessary with this line:

```
$cardTypes = $cardTypeAPIAccessor->getCardTypes();
```

So it would seem to me that in your loop, you just need:

```
foreach ($cardTypes as $cardType){
?>
 <tr>
    <td class="numeric"><?php echo $cardType->getCardTypeId(); ?></td>
    <td class="numeric"><?php echo $cardType->getCategory(); ?></td>
 </tr>
```

Although that is really just a guess based on the given code and the missing `CardType` class. But I don't see the need to generate new objects inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The `$cardType` variable is an instance of the CardType class, not an array. The problem is you are using it as though it were an array, when it is an object. So this

```
$cardType['card_type_id']
```

Should be

```
$cardType->getCardTypeID()
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes your response becomes object-based that can not easily access. use case like when you get data from a different controller in a controller or any third-party API.

so you can get data using this way

```
$object->getData(1);   // here 1 is for associated data form.
```

In my use case, I was facing the same problem when I try to access data from a different controller.

```
    $attendanceController =  new AttendanceController();

    $offDayData =  $attendanceController->getAttendanceOffDays($req);

    return  $offDayData->getData(1)['response'];
```

When you try to get data from a **Controller Class** then response wrapped in a different way.  so that you have to use **getData(1)** method for access that response. in my solution i used that. it will work in all case then you want to get data from different 
**ControllerCalss**